# Product image cache resized

Tags: image, product-images, image-preview, image-upload

Where can I define the size of the product image cache?

Our product-image in product image cache now automatically will be scaled down from 1900 pixels to 600 pixels.
But I want to keep the original size on product page, because details are important for us.

Comment: just make sure you have uploaded original image, if so check its size that saved in `catalog/product/firstletter/secondletter/` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Magento shouldn't resize the zoomed in image on the product detail page, so I'm guessing you are using a default theme so look for a file that replaces the standard Magento `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` file.

There you should have some code that looks like this:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(600);
```

Just remove the `resize` method

Answer (score 1):

Check your product image size in directory `media/catalog/product/firstcharacterofimagename/secondcharacterofimagename/` for file `imagename`.

Then compare the size with the image showing in frontend, if both are not same then check your `theme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` file for `resize()` function whether any resizing is applied or not.